# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node. at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, dom, append, addeventlistener, removechild

```
let inputValue = document.querySelector('.input')
let button = document.querySelector('.button')
let items = document.querySelector('#ul')

button.addEventListener('click', function (){
    let li = document.createElement('li')
    let deleteBtn = document.createElement('X')
    deleteBtn.textContent = 'X'
    li.textContent = inputValue.value
    li.appendChild(deleteBtn)
    items.appendChild(li)

    let removeBtn = document.querySelector('#ul')
    removeBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        let targetBtn = e.target.parentNode
        items.removeChild(targetBtn)
    })

})
```

Hi everyone, I am just a newbie in programming. I just created a todolist app in Js. In the above code, the remove button that i created works fine but it shows error in the console. Can anyone help me what is actually happening as I tried several approach, none of did work for me. Thank you

Comment: Before going deeper, first thing I notice is this line: let deleteBtn = document.createElement('X'). This creates a custom (unknown) <x> node. You probably don't want to do that. let deleteBtn = document.createElement('BUTTON') seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the `event listener` on the `ul` element, you need to add it to the `deleteBtn` element, and when `clicked` it should remove the `li` element.

```
button.addEventListener('click', function (){
    let li = document.createElement('li')
    let deleteBtn = document.createElement('button')
    deleteBtn.textContent = 'X'
    li.textContent = inputValue.value
    li.appendChild(deleteBtn)
    items.appendChild(li)

    deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
       li.remove()
    })

})
```